# Is there an easy way to customize a QProgressBar?

Tags: qt, qprogressbar

I would like to have a QProgressBar that ends with a dot ( that has a bigger width than the width of the line ). What do I have to override, or what property/attribute would I have to set to achieve this effect ?

EDIT : here is a pic of how I would like it to look like :

[picture http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/48ea9662cd.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/48ea9662cd.png)

Where would I have to start? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass QProgressBar, add the dot to the class as a QLabel, then use setPixmap() on the QLabel. You will need to overload the paintEvent() for your widget to move the dot to the right position.

Comment: You could use a QFrame to draw the line